# Creating table in Excel using VBscript gives Invalid error

Tags: excel, vbscript, create-table

I am running VB script using cscript in Windows 7. The following code produces runtime "Invalid procedure call or argument" error with creating table using ListObjects.

```
Set ExcelObject = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
ExcelObject.visible = True
ExcelObject.WorkBooks.Add 'Adds a workbook to an excel object
Set mySheet = ExcelObject.Sheets(1)
mySheet.Activate
mySheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, mySheet.Range("A1:D10"), , xlYes).Name = "myTable"
```

Comment: What problem are you having? Is there an error?

Comment: Are you using VBScript (note - "VBA script" is not a thing)? If Yes then VBScript has no idea what the values of `xlSrcRange` and `xlYes` are (since they are only defined in Excel VBA), so you need to substitute the actual values of those constants.

Comment: Tim, thanks for solving the problem. I'm running VBScript (if I understood correctly). The request for creating the table was not materializing with Excel. Once the xlSrcRange and slYes were changed to local constants the solution worked. I learned something new!

Answer (score 0):

Not really knowing what problems you are having with this... I'll venture to guess that you'll probably want to grab the workbook object that is spit out from the workbooks.add method. You can then use that reference your sheet since `worksheets` or `sheets` is not a collection of an excel application, but rather a workbook.

```
Set ExcelObject = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
ExcelObject.visible = True
set wb = ExcelObject.WorkBooks.Add 'Adds a workbook to an excel object
Set mySheet = wb.Sheets(1)
mySheet.Activate
mySheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, mySheet.Range("A1:D10"), , xlYes).Name = "myTable"
```

Comment: JNevill, thanks for looking into this request. Tim's suggestion solved it for me.